# Ruby undefined method `mtime' for <Net::SFTP::Request:0x007fa2799d41d0> (NoMethodError) I thought .mtime was defined by the previous string

Tags: ruby, ssh, find, sftp

Is working up until line 56, i wonder if i'm using mtime correctly, i thought the string before.mtime defined it. I am also not sure which mtime is causing the error, here is line 56:

if File.stat(local_file).mtime > Time.at(rstat.mtime)

This is the error I get when I run this code bellow:

```
box.ru:56:in `block (3 levels) in <main>': undefined method `mtime' for #<Net::SFTP::Request:0x007fa2799d41d0> (NoMethodError)
```

rstat = sftp.stat(remote_file) so the second mtime should be defined too, unless remote_file is mis configured.. thanks for taking a look!

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'rubygems'
require 'net/ssh'
require 'net/sftp'
require 'highline/import'
require 'find'

host = 'server'
local_path = '/Users/awesome1/Development/box'
remote_path = '/home/awesome2/box'

def sanitize_string(string_name)
string_name.gsub(/[^\w\.\-]/,"_")
end


puts "box username:"
user0 = gets.chomp
user = sanitize_string(user0)

pass0 = ask("Enter password for #{user}: ") { |q| q.echo = false }
pass = sanitize_string(pass0)

puts 'connecting to box...'
Net::SSH.start( host, user, :password => pass ) do|ssh|
result = ssh.exec!("cd #{remote_path} && ls")
 puts result
   ssh.sftp.connect do |sftp| 
 puts 'Checking for files which need updating'
 Find.find(local_path) do |local_file|
     next if File.stat(local_file).directory?
     remote_file = remote_path + local_file.sub(local_path, '')

     begin
     remote_dir = File.dirname(remote_file)
     sftp.stat(remote_dir)
 rescue Net::SFTP::Operations::StatusException => e
   raise unless e.code == 2
   sftp.mkdir(remote_dir, :mode => dir_perm)
 end 
   begin
   rstat = sftp.stat(remote_file)
 rescue Net::SFTP::Operations::StatusException => e
   raise unless e.code == 2
   sftp.put_file(local_file, remote_file)
   sftp.setstat(remote_file, :permissions => file_perm)
   next
 end

 if File.stat(local_file).mtime > Time.at(rstat.mtime)
   puts "Copying #{local_file} to #{remote_file}"
   ssh.sftp.upload(local_file, remote_file)
  end
 end
end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

1) Don't ever post on stack overflow or any other computer programming forum unless your code is properly indented.

> ```
> if File.stat(local_file).mtime > Time.at(rstat.mtime)
> ```
>
> This is the error I get when I run this code bellow:
>
> ```
> box.ru:56:in block (3 levels) in <main>': undefined method mtime' for 
> <Net::SFTP::Request:0x007fa2799d41d0> (NoMethodError)
> ```

2) The error message implies that rstat is an object of type `Net::SFTP::Request`, and if you look through the `NET::SFTP` docs here:

http://net-ssh.rubyforge.org/sftp/v2/api/

you will discover that mtime() is not an instance method of the `Net::SFTP::Request` class, i.e. you can't call mtime() on a `Net::SFTP::Request` object.

The line:

```
ssh.sftp.connect do |sftp|
```

assigns an object of type `NET::SFTP::Session` to sftp, so sftp.stat() must return an object of type `Net::SFTP::Request`.  If you look at the docs for `NET::SFTP::Session#stat()` they refer you to the lstat() docs, and if you click the link for lstat(), the lstat() docs say:

> The method returns immediately with a Request object.

Is the class really named just "Request"? Click on the "Request" link and at the top of the page you will see:

```
Net::SFTP::Request
```

...and there is no method named mtime() listed for that class.  Maybe the mtime() method is included in some parent class or a module that is included somewhere?  The parent class is listed as Object(right under where it says `Net::SFTP::Request`), and `Net::SFTP::Request` has one included module called `Constants::PacketTypes`--but there's no mtime() method in either Object or `Constants::PacketTypes`.

For some reason, you seem to think that `sftp.stat(remote_file)` returns a File object--it doesn't; sftp.stat() returns a `Net::SFTP::Request` object.  However, if you specify a block when you call stat() (see the lstat() docs), then the block will be passed a Net::SFTP::Response object, and according to the lstat() docs:

> The :attrs property of the response will contain an Attributes
>   instance appropriate for the the protocol version (see
>   Protocol::V01::Attributes, Protocol::V04::Attributes, and
>   Protocol::V06::Attributes).

Checking the doc for Protocol::V06::Attributes reveals there is an :mtime attribute in the response, and:

> all of the above attributes are exposed as methods (though not all
>   will be set with non-nil values from the server).

Going back to the lstat() docs and looking at the example again reveals that you have do something like this:

```
request = sftp.stat(remote_file) do |response|
  raise "fail!" unless response.ok?

  remote_file_mtime = response[:attrs].mtime
end

request.wait
```